# PHP update timestamp in MySQL table via PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Thanks for the help, in advance. I'm new to PHP so please bear with me.

I have the following `foreach` loop:

```
1 foreach($killOrder as $k){
2     $toTime = strtotime($k['timediff']);
3     $fromTime = strtotime("now");
4     if (($fromTime - $toTime) > 5400){
5         $db->update_order($k, array('orderfulfilled_ts'=>date('Y-M-d H:i:s')));
6     } else {
7         echo '<p>still time</p>';
8     }
9 }
```

The array $killOrder contains ID=>1234 timediff=>0000-00-00 00:00:00

If you look at line 5, its currently updating a column `orderfulfilled_ts` in a table with the current time stamp. What I would like it to do is update `orderfulfilled_ts` with the time stamp from `$killOrder['timediff']`.

The function update_order is:

```
function update_order($id, $args) {
    return $this->update_row(REGION_PREFIX."Order", $id, $args);
}
```

So I'm not sure if I should be saving `$killOrder['timediff']` in a variable first and then formatting it to pass or if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: If those are indeed the values of `$k` line 5 is never going to execute.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Then should I store the time stamp from timediff then use that to pass in line 5? Thanks for all your help

Comment: You're asking a question without a real problem. I don't know whether it's okay to pass those parameters in line 5 because I don't have any context about what you're trying to do and what `update_order` does.